# Store elements from a ListView into a List

Tags: c#, winforms, list, listview

Since I haven't found anything that helped, I ask my question here:

I have a ListView where I select a whole row by click. Now I want to store these selected items into a List but don't know how this should work exactly.

```
       List<String> itemSelected = new List<String>();

        foreach (var selectedRow in listView1.SelectedItems)
        {
            itemSelected.Add(selectedRow);
        }
```

That doesn't work because I need an index (selectedRow[?]) or something like that. How can I store the values of the first column when clicked the row?

EDIT: The problem is that the ListViewItems have the type "object"

The ListView gets populated this way:

```
 using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionQuery))
            {
                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
                {
                    col1 = row.Cells[col1.Text].Value.ToString();
                    col2 = row.Cells[col2.Text].Value.ToString();

                    col1Cells.Add(col1);
                    col2Cells.Add(col2);
                }

            }
```

Comment: It's data from a GridView. I edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
ListViewItem listViewItem = this.listView1.SelectedItems.Cast<ListViewItem>().FirstOrDefault();
if (listViewItem != null)
{
    string firstColumn = listViewItem.Text;
    string secondColumn = listViewItem.SubItems[0].Text;
    // and so on with the SubItems
}
```

---

If you have more selected items and only need the values of the first columns you can use:

```
List<string> values = listView1.SelectedItems.Cast<ListViewItem>().Select(listViewItem => listViewItem.Text).ToList();
```

Comment: One can select multiple items and I just need to store the values of the first column into my List

Comment: Thank you a lot! That helped me to solve my problem!

Answer (score 0):

It's common to bind a ListView to the List of non-trivial types.

Then you can handle SelectedItemChanged or something like that. You receive the whole object (in type `object`) which you can cast to your custom type and retrieve any properties you want

Comment: How to cast that the right way? I changed the List now to an ArrayList and it stores them but I want them as Integers.